# Jquery Ajax or Get doesn't work on SOME IE

Tags: jquery, ajax, internet-explorer, get

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){

            function listadepoimentos(page){
                //  $.get("ajaxes.php", {act:'listadepoimentos', page:page}, function a(b){$('#holder').html(b)}, "text");
                $.ajax({
                    type: 'GET',
                    url: 'ajaxes.php',
                    data: {act:'listadepoimentos', page:page},
                    success: function(data){
                            //alert(data);
                            $('#holder').html(data);
                    },
                    error: function(xhr, type, exception){
                            alert("Error: " + type);
                    }
                });
            }

            listadepoimentos(0);

        });


    </script>
```

It works fine on all browsers but SOME ie8. Yes, SOME. I've tried various ie8 browsers and in some of these it works, some not.

Is there a reasonable answer?

Comment: When using AJAX GET on IE, you should always specify `cache: false`. Either way, what isn't working properly? Are your getting an error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well,well... after almost about 3 weeks of ie terror we finally found the solution. Our bugged users reset their ie8 prefereces to default. And... voi'a'la it simple start to work!!!!!!!!!!! Don't ask me why, or which setting is the responsabile for this bug.

I was using $.get all over the site. So the $.ajax solution is about to be abandonned. Reseting the ie8 defaults makes $.get start to work properly.